# Can PowerShell know all apps in the start menu?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

When I click the Windows button, I can type the name of an app and get completions in the menu to quickly find an app and run it.

But it looks like with PowerShell I must add the app's path to $ENV:Path which is very cumbersome to do per app. Is there a better way?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you just need a list of every program installed on your pc?

Comment: What is a star menu?

Comment: @FoxDeploy: not exactly. I want to be able to invoke them as if they are in my path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of, but not really.  PowerShell's tab completion function searches the current folder, known cmdlet names, and folders in the user and system path.  Unless you want to rewrite the tab completion function yourself (which is possible, see [PowerTab](http://powertab.codeplex.com/)) you're stuck with that functionality.

You should be able to use `Start-Process` (alias `start` and `saps`), which does use some file association information similar to the Start Menu.  However, you need to know the name of the application executable, not the friendly name you'd see on the Start Menu.  You can't type `Start-Process word`.  You'd have to say `Start-Process winword`, because the executable is `winword.exe`.

PowerShell is a modern command line, but it's still a command line.  It doesn't help the user the same way the Windows search does because it doesn't make the same assumptions.  PowerShell assumes you'll predominantly want to work with cmdlets, and that's really how most people use it, IMX.  Unless you're managing servers, it's not meant to replace the GUI.

You can use tab completion with the folder names and the call operator, so you could type `C:\Pro` and hit tab and it will expand to (for example) `& 'C:\Program Files\'`.  Note that it includes the call operator (`&`) for you here automatically, since the provider for file systems assumes you'll want it.

Answer (score 0):

A trick I use is to create a batch file for things I use a lot from the command line and put that in a c:\tools folder, which is in my system path.
That way you don't have to add every executable to your path so it can find it with autocomplete.